# Depricate indexing numeric types in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `json` documents with price fields and this prices by nature are distinct.
Can I or Should I depricate to create reverse index if I don't want to search by this fields. And I think this is not good to store such unique fields in index when using search like elastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [disable the indexing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html) of certain fields if you want

```
PUT test_lalilulelo_1986
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "price": {
        "enabled": "false"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Ingest document**

```
POST test_lalilulelo_1986/_doc
{
  "price": 100
}
```

**Queries**

```
POST test_lalilulelo_1986/_search
```

Returns the document

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_lalilulelo_1986",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "x2wsEXgBLiMtJ3pUffYA",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 100
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This one returns no documents even if the price is greater than 10

```
POST test_lalilulelo_1986/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "price": {
        "gte": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No results

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

The value can still be retrieved from the `_source` field, but it is not searchable or stored in any other way